# Errors when passing variable to a function javascript not allowing changes to CSS

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, asp.net

I have a partial view in Asp.Net that has a table in it. the id to that table is set to the validity it has been passed for example "Error", "Warning" or "Valid" and set using

'class=".@validity.ToString()"'

I use a button to call the function:

```
 <button onclick=collapse(@validity.ToString())">Collapse</button>
```

Script is

```
@section scripts
{
    <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
        var x = false;
        function collapse(cls) {
            x = !x;
            var add = '.';
            var Class = add.concat(cls);
            if(x)
                $(Class)
                    .css({
                        'display': 'none'
                    });
            else {
                $(Class)
                    .css({
                        'display': 'table-row'
                    });
            }
        };
    </script>
}
```

Don't know why this isn't allowing the `Class` to set which table the css changes

Comment: Any errors in console? Have you tried adding a breakpoint and debug? It can be that the selector need to be wrapped in quotes, `$("Class")`

Comment: typo: onclick=collapse()" => onclick="collapse()"

Answer (score 0):

If `validity` is a string, or you're converting it to a string, it needs to be wrapped in quotation marks to pass it to a Javascript function.  You can do this the hard way, or install Json.Net and do this:

```
<button onclick=collapse(@(Html.Raw(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(validity))))">Collapse</button>
```